# Touch screen not working on an HP Touch-smart 610

Tags: 12.04, hp, touchscreen

I have a hp touch-smart 610, and with ubuntu 11.10 everything works out of the box. I tried with the live cd to ubuntu 12.04 and sadly, the touch-screen don't work. I would like to install 12.04, but don't want to lose the touch-screen.

Comment: Can you identify your touchscreen model with `lsusb`?

Comment: If I use the code 'xinput --list' I can see it is a Quanta OpticalTouchScreen.

Comment: Does `lsusb | grep Quanta` show something? Is it `0408:3000`?

Comment: Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0408:3008 Quanta Computer, Inc.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same device on which I installed ub 12.04 (64 bits), I also asked a question about it a while ago. For me also the touchscreen does not work from the live CD. You need to install, then update the system, and then remove a certain section from a Xorg configuration file to make things "work".

See here my question and the solution: [Mouse selects everything on its own](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143015/mouse-selects-everything-on-its-own)

(I do not guarantee that it will work for you. Also I do not multitouch, just singletouch. The device should however be able to do multitouch.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/913164

Must be fixed in linux 3.2.0-24.37. Search the page for "3008" to get an additional info.

Comment: It help partly, I go the touch-screen to work, but only with one finger tap and not with two finger tap

Comment: I think you need to file a new bug report with `apport-bug linux`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing with 12.04 and LXDE, eeepc 701 with eGalaxy touchscreen, seems solved with the update in this ppa via Ubuntu Tweak: "xorg-edgers fresh X crack", which installed the package `xserver-xorg-core 2:1.12.3+git20120709`.