# Mouse selects everything on its own

Tags: gnome, mouse

I have a strange problem that my mouse keeps selecting everything I point to. For example, if I open Rhythmbox, then at the top of the screen there is a text which says which song is playing. If I move my mouse over this text, then it will select this text; but I am not clicking.

This behaviour does not happen in all programs. For example in Firefox I have no problem at all. Maybe it is Gtk related? Nautilus also behaves strangely; I cannot open files by clicking on them, I have to select and make a box around the file and then press enter to open it. If I click, then nothing happens. Similar problems also happen with other Gtk software.

I think the problem might be related to touchscreen issues (I have a touchscreen). I run Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 12.04. I have a HP touchsmart 610 desktop computer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I just did a fresh reinstall, and I am 90% certain that it is related to the touchscreen drivers. Here is what happens when I reinstall. At first boot, so exactly after install, everything works fine, except the touchscreen: The  touchscreen does not respond. I update ubuntu, because I installed from an old CD (CD with ub. 12.04). Then on next reboot I have touchscreen working , but the working touchscreen comes together with the mouse selecting everything on its own.

SECOND QUESTION: Would anybody know how I could figure out what those touchscreen drivers are (so that I can disable them) ?

Comment: Try hitting escape a few times, our tapping your touchpad.  I've had this at times when using my laptop with the touchpad-type mouse.  Unfortunately, this may just be a bug.  Try to find out if you can reliably reproduce it.

Comment: it is easy to reproduce, because it always happens with no exception. Go into the program, and Gnome will think I have my mouse clicked and select things I move over.

Comment: You might try looking on launchpad for a similar bug.  (You can see my profile for the 'how to report a bug' link, as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in X and it's already [reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1002788). Sadly it took a while for them to realize that it's made by X.

Answer (score 45):

## Touch your screen to make it stop.

I have the same problem on a touchscreen machine. It just happened now, and I decided to see if someone offered a solution. @mnr's mention that it might be touchscreen-related made me try: **Touching the screen made the mouse stop auto-highlighting.**

Comment: I used to get so frustrated, I'd save everything and reboot to resolve this issue! I finally found this, and yes, touching the screen "fixes" the problem (In Ubuntu 18.04 with Dell XPS 9560). Thanks, @Rasmus!

Comment: I was suspecting a hardware issue on my 5 year old Lenovo Y70-70 Touch and after so many annoying reboots you saved my day, @Rasmus

Comment: This is Awesome. Laptop Asus UX501J with Touchscreen. Thanks!

Comment: Dell XPS15 and many reboots later, you'll save me some time, thanks !

Comment: In my case I had to use 2 fingers to touch the screen...

Comment: Simple solution, touch the screen. Love it. Saved me a couple of hours of going down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 7):

Got to *System Settings -> Universal Access -> Pointing and Clicking*:

[image]

Make sure you have not activated **Hover Click**

Comment: thanks for the idea, unfortunately hover click is not enabled.

Comment: so this is not the issue. I think it has something to do with touchscreen drivers

Comment: @meneer: driver or even hardware issue seems likely. I made the answer for people that may come here from the title ;)

Comment: Hi Takkat. I just did a fresh reinstall, and I am 90% certain that it is related to the touchscreen drivers. Here is what happens when I reinstall. At first boot, so exactly after install, everything works fine, except the touchscreen: The  touchscreen does not respond. I update ubuntu, because I installed from an old CD (CD with ub. 12.04). Then on next reboot I have touchscreen working , but the working touchscreen comes together with the mouse selecting everything on its own.

Comment: @Takkat: I had a similar problem in Ubuntu 16.04, and this solved my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was my mouse cord on top of the touchpad the one created the mayhem.  It took me a shameful time to figure this out...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with a touchscreen.
The solution proposed by Rasmus (touch the screen) solved the problem.
If (like me) you don't use the touch screen without a pen, you can disable the "finger" part of it using the following command:

```
xinput disable "$( xinput list | grep -i Finger | sed '/Finger/s/^.*id=\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/' )"
```

(you can reenable it using the `xinput enable` command with the same argument)