# Mouse randomly selects and clicks in wrong location, cannot open files/folders

Tags: mouse

My problem is a bit like the issue given here: [Mouse selects everything on its own](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143015/mouse-selects-everything-on-its-own) except it occurs in both Gnome 3 and Unity.  It doesn't happen in all applications though.  So far I've observed it primarily in MATLAB (R2012a), Nautilus, Chromium and the Gnome and/or Unity dialog boxes.  Essentially I'll go to click something (like to go to a certain location in the MATLAB editor, or to click a button on a system dialog box) and instead of clicking where I pointed, the click is performed somewhere else, perhaps opening another menu or even selecting a large chunk of text in an arbitrary part of the screen.  Furthermore, Nautilus recognizes left and right clicks but never at the location I actually clicked.  However, dragging works.

It happens whether I am using the touchscreen (HP TX2) or a wireless mouse, or the touchpad.  I am on Ubuntu 12.04, and I have also uninstalled Compiz to no effect.  If I reboot the problem sometimes disappears, but it either comes back after a few minutes or if I suspend and resume.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am getting the same problem, but so far only in some parts of MATLAB R2011b.

Comment: Same problem here. I have 64bit matlab 7.11.0 (2010b) under ubuntu gnome-shell 3.4.1

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I had the same problem and it only appeared when the window was maximised. The mouse cursor was exactly offset by the offset that the orginal un-maximised window had from the upper left corner of the screen. I can thus work around that bug by first moving the unmaximised window to the upper left corner and then clicking maximise.