# Mouse selects without clicking, like a webpage

Tags: xorg

When my Dell System XPS L322X laptop, running Ubuntu 12.04, is connected to the Dell P2314H external monitor (this model does NOT have touch screen), the mouse selects anything it hovers over without actually clicking.  Note: monitor connected to laptop's mini display port with a DVI cable and a DVI/mini-display-port adapter.

Other notes: I have an external mouse and keyboard connected to a USB hub which is connected to one of the laptop's two USB 3.0 ports. To avoid hibernating when laptop lid is closed, I set IgnoreLid=true in /etc/UPower/UPower.conf

I looked at [Mouse selects everything on its own](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143015/mouse-selects-everything-on-its-own); Universal Access's Hover Click is OFF.  I then checked https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1002788 as well as http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9999160 which suggest it's due to touchscreen (again, this doesn't have touchscreen) and, therefore, to use: xinput set-prop 'NAME OF MY TOUCHSCREEN DEVICE' 'Device Enabled' 0 (after first showing list of input devices using: xinput --list).  But ... I don't have touchscreen for this.

Output of xinput --list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ CyPS/2 Cypress Trackpad                   id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M             id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: reinstall the mouse driver: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-mouse && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mouse`

Comment: This only happens when you connect the second display? How it identifies itself the monitor?